# How to override username validation in Django

Tags: django

I have a simple profile form that displays the users profile and allows them to make updates to Full Name, Initials, Username and Bio.  In my Profile model, I have Username set to unique with field validation.  It is more of a screen-name reference field, as email is used for login, however it still needs to be unique and the user can change this name if needed.

The issue is that validation does not pass form.is_valid(), even when user does not change their username, but updates other fields, due to the fact that the username does already exist for the request user.  How can I get around this issue.

Sample of what i am trying to do:

```
If username == form['username'].value()  (meaning username is unchanged)
  allow form.save()

else if form.is_valid():  (perform normal validation checks)
  form.save()
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Profile Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    
    # OneToOneField ensures that only one user can have one profile
    my_user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    # Extension of additional user information
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True)
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=False, null=True)
    
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username', max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.',
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': "Username already exists.",
        },
    )

    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Form

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('full_name', 'initials', 'username', 'bio')

        widgets = {
            'full_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'id':'full_name', 'placeholder': 'Full Name'}),
            'initials': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'id':'initials', 'maxlength': '3', 'placeholder': 'Initials'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-3', 'id':'username', 'placeholder': 'Username'}),
            'bio': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':5, 'cols':8}),
        }
```

Views post function

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
        
        email = self.request.user
        my_user = Profile.objects.get(my_user=email)

        if my_user.username == form['username'].value():
            #need to override username validation on field for current user
            pass
        else:
            if form.is_valid():
                # Update Profile Information
                my_user.full_name = form.cleaned_data['full_name']
                my_user.initials = form.cleaned_data['initials']
                my_user.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                my_user.bio = form.cleaned_data['bio']
                my_user.save()
                # Send Success Message To User
                messages.success(request, 'Profile has been updated.')
                # Update Session Variables
                request.session['full_name'] = my_user.full_name
                request.session['initials'] = my_user.initials
                request.session['username'] = my_user.username
        
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Template

```
{% extends 'account/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head_title %}Manage Profile{% endblock %}

{% block base_content %}
<h6 class="text-center">Manage Account Profile</h6>
<hr>
<div class="py-3">
    <form id="profile_form" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_profile' %}" class="col-sm-8 mx-auto small">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Update Profile</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I didnt clearly understand your question. I'm guessing you're getting error while updating user form. something like "unique constraint failed" on username. In  that case you are not updating user, you are creating a new one. Can you please, show your view and clearify your question.

Comment: Added views post function for clarification.  I am currently not getting an error.  The form will not post due to not passing form validation on the username field.  For example, if i am simply updating my bio on the profile, but don't update my username, form validation - "user already exists"

Comment: Can you post your template as well? More information you provide, more chances to get your issue solved.

Comment: template added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using model form any way you can pass a profile instance to your form if you want to update that Profile. Try this.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = Profile.objects.get(my_user = request.user)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance = obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Profile has been updated.')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

Comment: well that was easy.  thanks for the answer.  worked perfectly!